# How do i set/retrieve value from dictionary in list?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, object, escaping

So I am able to retrieve the elements.handle but i am unable to retrieve elements.handle~. Is there any possible way to do so?

I've tried escape character elements['handle\~'] but it does not seem to work

```
{"elements":[{"handle":"urn:li:emailAddres:7440721026","handle~":{"emailAddress":"abc@gmail.com"}}]}
```

Comment: How are you trying to retrieve it?

Comment: I just want to retrieve "abc@gmail.com" but the tilde in "handle~" is an issue

Comment: `string sData =  @"{ ""elements"":[{""handle"":""urn:li:emailAddres:7440721026"",""handle~"":{""emailAddress"":""abc@gmail.com""}}]}";
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sData);
            Console.WriteLine(data.elements[0]["handle~"]);` - Try this - Add NewtonsoftJson.Net as dll reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the value you are looking for (`abc@gmail.com`) is nested a few layers deep.  If you want to retrieve it, you'll need to access it accordingly.

```cs
var data = "{\"elements\":[{\"handle\":\"urn:li:emailAddres:7440721026\",\"handle~\":{\"emailAddress\":\"abc@gmail.com\"}}]}";

dynamic x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);

// x is an object with one property: elements
Console.WriteLine($"x: {x}");

// x.elements is a List (based on your question)
Console.WriteLine($"x.elements: {x.elements}");

// x.elements[0] is a Dictionary (based on your question)
Console.WriteLine($"x.elements[0]: {x.elements[0]}");

// x.elements[0]["handle~"] is another Dictionary
Console.WriteLine($"x.elements[0][handle~]: {x.elements[0]["handle~"]}");

// x.elements[0]["handle~"]["emailAddress"] is the value you want
Console.WriteLine($"x.elements[0][handle~][emailAddress]: {x.elements[0]["handle~"]["emailAddress"]}");
```

That means `x.elements[0]["handle~"]["emailAddress"]` should get you `abc@gmail.com`.